# Using django-storages and the s3boto backend: x-amz-security-token is appended which I do not want

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto

I'm serving static content from s3 with django-storages. This works fine when using boto 2.5.X. But when I use boto >= 2.6  the url to s3 media get mangled; an extra variable is appended. The difference is that the x-amz-security-token gets appended (which I do not want). The media is not accessible at the url.

In my settings.py I use

```
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

The bad url:

```
https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/style/css/layout.min.css?x-amz-security-token=AQoDYXdzEKj/76aRNkwEaoALUm866M8Z6Kc4aF/76aRNkjDcT70xSVB58kR%2BONYLf7y1z1pgqUX7fPRXVQjP9DYOZzcVdHCV27zybD/iPYT2C6rCEnvkQvhcq....
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: nope... still working with old version of boto

Comment: Old question, but I'm seeing this behavior with current boto (2.42) and django-storages (1.5) *only* when using an EC2 IAM role. Appears to be a [long-standing boto bug](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/1477). And [this workaround](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/1477#issuecomment-38759048) worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have a better work around based on django-storages (version 1.1.8) which is

```
 AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com'
```

This avoids django-storage calling boto's `generate_url` and just stitchs together the path to the resource. If you want to use auth to get you static files this won't work.

For the curious:

Static files on some parts of my site worked and other parts, like the admin, didn't work. That was connected to the difference between

```
{% load static %}
```

and

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Both define a block tag `{% static %}`, but they do different things. The one from static just prepends {{ STATIC_URL }}, the one from staticfiles using the storage's `url` method to get the url for the file. The django admin's `{% static %}` block from `admin_static` acts like the `staticfiles` one, using the storage.

By changing to using `{% load staticfiles %}` my site was equally broken everywhere when `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False` and/or `AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False`. That pointed to the problem being basically in boto `generate_url`, that when `querystring_auth` is `False`, the `x-amz-security-token` still got set.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this in you settings.py

> AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False

Comment: I believe the AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS setting controls https vs http urls, and is unrelated to adding the querystring auth.